# The most likely minimum value after k iterations (or runs)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have a (continuous) probability distribution defined by its cumulative distribution function. Suppose now that we pick at random $k$ values. Is there a formula that gives the value x that have the most likelihood to be the minimum?

Comment: You (that means you Med) should be able to give the probability that all of the $k$ values exceed a given value $x$ in terms of $F(x)$.  Careful use of differentiation may then indicate the mode of the distribution of the minimum, though this will depend on the particular starting distribution

Comment: Well ok if we consider the the simple case when $k=1$. If we maximise $1-
 F(x)$, the value of $x$ that corresponds to the maximum gives the value that is most likely to be less then any outcome. Does this mean that this $x$ is the most likely value to be THE minimum?

Answer (score 1):

Let the cumulative distribution function be

$$F(x)=\mathrm{Pr}\,(X\leq x).$$

Then the distribution of the minimum $X_{\min}\equiv\min(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_k)$ satisfies

$$\mathrm{Pr}\,(X_{\min}>x)=\mathrm{Pr}(X_1>x)\,\mathrm{Pr}\,(X_2>x)\,\cdots\,\mathrm{Pr}(X_k>x)=[1-F(x)]^k.$$

The cumulative distribution function of $X_{\min}$ is then $F_{\min}(x)=1-[1-F(x)]^k$. The probability density function is therefore

$$p_{\min}(x)=\frac{dF_{\min}(x)}{dx}=k\,[1-F(x)]^{k-1\,}p(x),$$

where $p(x)=dF(x)/dx$ is the probability density function of one trial. The maximum of $p_{\min}(x)$ is obtained at

$$\frac{d\ln p_{\min}(x)}{dx}=-\frac{k-1}{1-F(x)}p(x)+\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)}=0.$$

Solve this equation given a distribution $F(x)$ to find the most likely minimum.

Comment: Thanks! That seems correct. I didnt get the last line though

Comment: Why did you do $\frac{d\ln p_{\min}(x)}{dx}?$  Shouldn't it be just $\frac{d p_{\min}(x)}{dx}$ ?

Comment: It's the same. Taking the log makes the calculation a bit easier.

Comment: Yes! Cool thanks!